# Pass value into stored procedure in T-SQL

Tags: t-sql, parameter-passing, azure-synapse

I am trying to pass a variable `@date` into my T-SQL command (in DB in Synapse). What I want it to do is to delete data from a table by given date defined by user.

Here is my script, which works just fine, when I define date inside it:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROC [DPIT].[proc_nhs_delete_by_date] @date datetime, @TableName sysname AS

BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @SchemaName sysname;

SET @SchemaName = N'DPIT';

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);
SET @SQL = N'DELETE FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@SchemaName) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + N' WHERE datum = @date;';
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL, N'@date datetime', @date

END
```

But when I execute this stored procedure and pass parameters into it, I get the following error:

```
Parse error at line: 3, column: 1: Incorrect syntax near 'EXEC'.
```

This is the code that creates the error:

```
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [DPIT].[proc_nhs_delete_by_date]
        @date = N'20231021',
        @TableName = sluzba_G

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

Do you know where the problem might be? I am inclining to believe that the problem is that Synapse probably does not support EXEC command and I will have to use `sys.sp_executesql` in some way, but to be honest, I do not know how.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thank you for your input! Unfortunately, this is for a project that we need to finish ASAP and we will be sending the input from Power Apps. It worked for us in other projects (not in Synapse though), so we would like to use proved methods, since we do not have time for more sophisticated solutions.

Comment: Why are you using "dynamic" SQL here, when the names of the objects are static; you assign the variable a static value. There's no need for this logic.

Comment: As Larnu said, why use that stored procedure in the first place when you end up executing a string that says `DELETE from schema.Table where date=@date`? With the schema and table hard-coded? Just execute the final statement

Comment: I was confused by the overcomplicated code and didn't realize it just deletes based on date. In almost every case in the past, such questions had to do with date-based tables. There's only a single table here. Why use such code?

Comment: I wouldn't use the SQL Server tag for questions on  Azure Synapse Analytics. It has a lot of differences from "regular" SQL Server

Comment: Heh, I had to double check when you made the comments I wasn't missing something, @PanagiotisKanavos ; though I'll admit I *assumed* the OP was doing the same when I first read the question.

Comment: This operation can be slow though, as each row deletion will be logged. If you have a lot of data by date you could use partitioning and remove old partitions from a table instantly . This is explained [here](https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-2016-enhancements-truncate-table-table-partitioning/) - you can switch partitions between the active and archive tables instantly, and then delete the archived partition. Or you can use `truncate with partitions` to erase one or more partitions.

Comment: @Larnu if there's a lot of data involved, partitions *should* be used to speed up deletions.

Comment: The objects will not be static eventually, I will need the @Table_name to be dynamic as well in the end. But currently I am stuck with executing stored procedure with passed parameters, therefore I work with this code for simplification.
UPDATE: I edited the code to see what I want it to look like in the end. Two parameters will be used in the final code

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - that syntax (`truncate with partitions`) isn't supported in the product they are using. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/truncate-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 - probably there is some alternative but I don't know it well enough

Comment: *Why* does it need to be dynamic..? Such requirements are normally the indication of an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info).

Comment: I have around 20 tables with monthly data. This will be a feature in Power Apps, that will allow end user to see data from the tables and delete the data in case he uploaded them incorrectly (he will be uploading the data into the database also via Power Apps).

Comment: So @PanagiotisKanavos *was* right, you're creating a table per month; that's just bad design.

Comment: @Larnu My bad with poor explanation. I have 20 tables that have data for all history (but the data being uploaded there are monthly). So the user can see a table COSTS for example, and the table stores all costs for Jan 21, Feb 21, Mar 22 etc... And this feature should enable him to delete data in COSTS for e.g. Jan 21.

Comment: @MedvidekPu the explanation was fine. The design is bad and the code you posted not the actual one. We can't tell you why code you didn't post fails, in a database that's not the one you specified. In a product called `Azure Data Warehouse` though, partitions are *essential* and how the product actually works. I wouldn't be surprised if `exec` was removed - it's not needed in a DW environment. Partitions on the other hand are essential for data management. If you had 1M rows per day, that `DELETE` would grow the transaction log by 1M records. With partitions though, you could just swap them

Comment: [Dynamic SQL for dedicated SQL pools in Azure Synapse Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-develop-dynamic-sql) explains that blob types like `varchar(max)` aren't supported in Azure Synapse. `DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);` isn't supported. As the doc explains, if the query is short enough to fit in a `varchar(8000)` or `nvarchar(4000)`, you can still use that. Otherwise you have to use `exec` with concatenated fragments

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thank you for the answer. I will use the patritions when I get the method with DELETE work, now I am focusing on having a working solution, even if it's not ideal. However, what do you mean by 'bad design' with storing monthly data in a table?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the MAX should not be the issue, but I changed it to 4000 to be sure. But I still can' find a way to make stored procedure ask for an input.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am confused here, the code I am using is posted above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic SQL aside, the problem you are experiencing is tooling. You cannot call a Stored Procedure in the default SSMS way in Synapse Dedicated SQL Pool (SQW Data Warehouse) using return.

Change this:

```
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [DPIT].[proc_nhs_delete_by_date]
        @date = N'20231021',
        @TableName = sluzba_G

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

To this:

```
EXEC    [DPIT].[proc_nhs_delete_by_date]
        @date = N'20231021',
        @TableName = sluzba_G
```

And it should work fine.

Comment: This was exactly the problem, thanks Joel:)

Comment: Also, a lot of people stated that dynamic SQL should be avoided (I work mainly with OOP, therefore I tend to use the same logic in SQL and parametrize everything). Could you recommend some literature dedicated to the problem of dynamic SQL? Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

@Larnu's comment needs highlighting:

> Why are you using "dynamic" SQL here, when the names of the objects are static; you assign the variable a static value. There's not need for this logic

Your code is vastly overcomplex and *scary* (dynamic SQL should put the fear in to everyone!).

Your code can be simplified to this:

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE DPIT.proc_nhs_delete_by_date (
 @date datetime
)
  AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  DELETE
  FROM   dbo.some_table
  WHERE  datum = @date
  ;
END
;
```

Comment: And even that would be needed only if someone wanted to allow people to perform that action without actually giving them DELETE permission to the table.